# create user account online whenever a contact is created

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I am using dynamics CRM 2013 on-premise. I want to create an account of customer on my website whenever the contact of customer is created in CRM. On creation of contact in CRM, customer will receive an email with a link and user credentials. When customer clicks on the link, he will be redirected to the webpage where he can sign in. upon signing in, he can see his contact details on webpage.

Can anyone suggest the simplest way of doing it?

Comment: You need to create a user, then becomes an O365 issue. Basically you will need to connect to your portal, and from there add a user and attach a license to him. I don't think it will be as simple as you would have liked.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do this. All i want is get customer details and write them on web.

Comment: I misunderstood then, if you have a website, and you want to give access to the website on user creation, you need to write a service that needs to be accessible by the plugin. In this case most of the actions that you need to take, are dependat on the way the website manages the subscription requests

Comment: yes, that is what i need. Could you please share some examples or link to do it

Comment: There isn't a "Standard" way to do it, you should create a web service that creates the users on the site by picking the values from the crm. So in the plugin collect the information that you need, on the website side you need to create a web service that receives the information coming from the plugin and creates the account. Again most of the work will be on the website side, the CRM plugin will connect and use that web service. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308359 try here to understand what i mean for web service, in those function you will need to create the user on the site side